# MySQL: Joining only on single row

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table `data` that looks like this

```
idOne | date | input
------------------
1 | 2015-01-01 | 423
2 | 2015-01-01 | 342
1 | 2015-01-02 | 343
2 | 2015-01-02 | 332
```

On this table I do:

```
SELECT date, SUM(input)
FROM data
WHERE date BETWEEN "2015-01-01" AND "2015-01-02"
GROUP BY date
```

This gives me this output:

```
date | input
------------------
2015-01-01 | 765
2015-01-02 | 675
```

I also have one more table in my DB, `info`:

```
idTwo | idOne | label
------------------
1 | 1 | 'Hello, '
2 | 2 | 'World!'
3 | 1 | 'Hello, '
4 | 2 | 'World!'
```

As you can see this database is not completely normalized, but this is what I have.

I would like to filter by the value of `label` in the `SELECT`-statement. This is giving me headaches! Every time I try my rows are summed multiple times. For instance:

```
SELECT date, SUM(input)
FROM data, info
WHERE date BETWEEN "2015-01-01" AND "2015-01-02"
AND data.idOne = info.idOne
AND label = 'Hello,'
GROUP BY date
```

Sums everthing twice and gives me this output:

```
date | input
------------------
2015-01-01 | 1530
2015-01-02 | 1350
```

How do I fix this? Thanks.

Comment: Can you edit your post and include the *expected* output?

Comment: You are joining on field `idOne` which for each value in table `date` exists twice in table `info`, thus the result.

Comment: Are you still working to figure this one out?

Comment: Gordon Linoff provided a great answer that solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

If you want accurate sums from the first table, then you probably need `exists`:

```
SELECT date, SUM(input)
FROM data d
WHERE date BETWEEN '2015-01-01' AND '2015-01-02' AND
      EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM info i WHERE d.idOne = i.idOne AND i.label = 'Hello,')
GROUP BY date;
```

You should also learn to use explicit `join` syntax.  Simple rule:  Never use commas in the `FROM` clause.

Comment: Can you explain the "never use commas in the from clause"?  I see you have a ton of rep but that statement doesn't make any sense to me and I've never seen ANYONE suggest that before.  Not disagreeing with using the JOIN syntax, that's a good point, but your statement seems mostly like opinion/style; please elaborate.

Comment: @Kalmino I've suggested it many times before, and many others have too.

Comment: @Strawberry - that's great, can you explain why?

Comment: There are several reasons. The most relevant are probably related to clarity, and ease of adaptability - changing an [INNER] JOIN to a LEFT [OUTER] JOIN for instance. However, the most important reason is perhaps to do with join precedence. While the rules determining the order in which joins precede (is that the right word) are clear, they'renot particularly memorable and can be confusing for even fairly experienced users (like me) - leading to unexpected results.

Comment: Thanks; good explanation.  I've got a good handle on the join precedence but the adaptability is a great point.  I'm still of the **opinion** that "never use commas in the `from` clause" is a bit too strong of a statement, but to each their own.

Comment: It's a good rule of thumb. You will find examples on SO where I've blatantly broken the rule, but I think it's a good rule nonetheless, and if you stick to it, you can't go too far wrong.

Comment: @Kalmino . . . Explicit joins support outer join syntax.  The comma does not.  Even databases that use (absurd) extensions don't have the full support for outer joins.  So, from a standard and functionality perspective, explicit joins are the right way to go.  In addition, most people find them easier to read.

Answer (score 0):

The sum is doubled, as you expect, because the rows are joined twice, since the id appears twice in the second table.

What you need to do, is extract that id from the second table so it appears once. You have to decide if you want the row with the highest or lowest id in the second table, but if you want max, try this:

```
SELECT MAX(idTwo), idOne, label
FROM info
GROUP BY idOne, label;
```

Then, since that will have only one row for each idOne (hopefully. This is not guaranteed as your table is not normalized like you said) you can join that to data and get the information you want:

```
SELECT dateCol, SUM(input)
FROM data
JOIN(
  SELECT MAX(idTwo), idOne, label
  FROM info
  GROUP BY idOne, label) tmp ON data.idOne = tmp.idOne
GROUP BY data.idOne;
```

Here is an [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b942f6/3) example.

Answer (score -1):

Did you mean this?

```
SELECT date, SUM(input) FROM data
WHERE date BETWEEN "2015-01-01" AND "2015-01-02"
AND idOne in (SELECT idtwo FROM info where label = 'Hello,')
GROUP BY date
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT date, SUM(input)
FROM data, (select distinct idOne from info where label = 'Hello') as info
WHERE date BETWEEN "2015-01-01" AND "2015-01-02"
AND data.idOne = info.idOne
GROUP BY date
```